# Key value is missing when I use axios

Tags: json, reactjs, axios

When I use axios to pull in JSON data, it does not bring in the initial key from the JSON.

If I import the wine list (JSON file) and console.log the response, it shows "wines:" and then the array of wines, that is what I want, but I need to use axios. When I use axios to get the JSON file, it only shows the number of items in the array and then the array of wines. Is there a way for axios to bring in that key value "wines"?

The JSON key I'm trying to get with the rest of the data is "wines":

`{`
 `"wines": [{`
    `"id": "f2ca57a5-d9da-4808-9164-8d6e0da0aef5",...`

This my axios call:

`const winesInfo = axios.get('/api/v1/wines').then(function(response) {`
    `console.log(response.data.wines);`
  `})`
  `.catch(function(error) {`
    `console.log(error);`
 `});`

What I want to console.log:

`{wines: Array(12)}`

What my console.log looks like:

`(12) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}]`

Comment: `console.log(response.data);`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to access response.data to get key wines but you are accessing response.data.wines so obviously you will get array of objects without key wines

So, response.data will give you what you want

Change

```
  const winesInfo = axios.get('/api/v1/wines').then(function(response) { console.log(response.data.wines); }).catch(function(error) { console.log(error); });
```

To

```
  const winesInfo = axios.get('/api/v1/wines').then(response => { console.log(response.data); }).catch(error => { console.log(error); });
```